# Filter out records from an array with no unique id

Tags: reactjs

I am trying to filter out records from one array if they exists in another array. Products is my initial array that contains all my products and productsToDelete contains 2 products as an example. What I am trying to achieve is, if productsToDelete has a product that already exists in Products it must filter it out. The issue I am facing is there is no unique key or ID, so I am having trouble comparing the array. Is it possible to compare the object in an array to another object.

Code:

```
const [products, setProducts] = useState<Product[]>([]);
const [productsToDelete, setProductsToDelete] = useState<Product[]>([]);


setProducts((products) =>
      products.filter((product) => product !== productsToDelete.map(val => val))
    );
```

Properties of Product array:

```
category: string;
subCategory: string;
name: string;
quantity: number;
price: number;
```

Comment: why don't you compare the name of the product

Comment: It is possible to have the same product name @BesufkadMenji

Comment: Why do you not have a unique id for each product? That is a major design flaw. Especially since products can have the same name. I suggest adding ids to your products.

Answer (score 1):

I agree with other comments: you should have a unique ID, for situations exactly like this. Technically, though, if the item is literally the same between the two arrays you can just directly compare them. Something like:

```
setProducts((products) =>
    products.filter((product) => productsToDelete.every(val => val !== product))
);
```